# Why fiddle code is not working on Plunker - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create tree-view like UI and found http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview

One [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/18/) here is working properly but when I am trying to make [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lEMegqgTeoyfOP6a18c6?p=preview) from it, its not working. What am i missing. I have properly imported external dependencies `angular.js` and `jquery.min.js` of Fiddle in my plunker

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery should be imported before angular.

Hence your code should look as follows:

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can find the updated working plunk at
http://plnkr.co/edit/SRoBKu?p=preview

Comment: Yes. Jquery should be before angular as I had mentioned and I have corrected the script tags. If jquery is not added before angular, Angular falls back to using JQLite which doesn't have all the features which the poster is using to display the tree model. Hence Jquery needs to be imported before angular.